# Bootstrap Collapse Widget not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have used Collapse in bootstrap to hide some information and display once button is click but I don't know that wrong on this one why it is not working.

```
<div id="myModal6" class="modal fade mdl" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title title_modal">Sample Data
               <span data-widget="collapse" tabindex="0" class="toggle-collapsed ui-collapse ui-toggle pull-right btn_details" role="button" aria-controls="toggle-pane-88" id="toggle-89" aria-expanded="false">Toggle</span>
            </h2>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="toggle-collapsed" aria-hidden="true" id="toggle-pane-88" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="toggle-89">This is my content!
            </p>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p class="headline_text">Sample again</p>
                  <p style="text-align:center"><img src="img/samp.jpg"
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p class="headline_text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                  <p style="text-align:center"><img src="img/samp21.jpg"/> </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I also include here files needed in bootstrap:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: I don't have an account & don't know how to use.

Comment: you don't need account to use fiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net go there paste your code with CDN link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to put a collapse panel inside your modal you need to add a target div for `#toggle-pane-88`. See example.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade mdl" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h2 class="modal-title title_modal">Sample Data
                  <span data-widget="collapse" tabindex="0" class="toggle-collapsed ui-collapse ui-toggle pull-right btn_details" role="button" aria-controls="toggle-pane-88" id="toggle-89" aria-expanded="false">Toggle</span>
                  </h2>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle-pane-88">Simple collapsible</button>
        <div id="toggle-pane-88" class="collapse">
          <p class="headline_text">Sample again</p>
          <p style="text-align:center">
            <img src="img/samp.jpg" </div>
            <p class="headline_text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="text-align:center">
              <img src="img/samp21.jpg" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It helps a lot.

Comment: It seems that the lastest bootstrap 5 version doesn't support this.

Comment: In boostrap 5 you need data-bs toggle and data-bs-target instead.